# Require certain JRE version

Tags: java

so my program uses API's that are only in Java 7. How can I make it so if someone does not have Java 7, I can make it tell them that they need it, instead of throwing an  unsupprotedClassVersionError. This needs to be multiplatform also! Thanks.

Comment: Tell them in the documentation.

Comment: @MattBall Sounds like you assume that users actually read those... :)

Comment: @uesr, java is cross-platform, so you don't need to consider multiplatform issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `java.version` property as part of your bootstrapping (in `main()` or as part of your loader).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Though, I've noticed a lot of applications that have specific JRE version requirements tend to distribute the JRE as part of the installation.